# Chart.js v2.9.3 not rendering on Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

`Chart.js v2.9.3` and below is not rendering at all on edge , but it is working fine on firefox and chrome.
Tried downgrading to 2.9.2 and 2.8 as well but no luck .

When i tried `chart.js v3-alpha2` it is working fine , but since it is still alpha version , i don't want to use it.

Please help , if anyone has come across same situation.

Comment: Also to add , i am not getting any error in  console.

Comment: Please provide more information, some code perhaps or an URL? Can you reproduce it on jsfiddle?

Comment: I was using charjs inside <td> of table , with some bootstrap classes , apparently that was not working on EDGE. I removed those classes and it is working fine now .